# Why are some BigQuery datasets from the same project not available in Monitoring?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have been trying to add some BigQuery Monitoring dashboards in GCP. Most of the datasets that appear for me under the SQL workspace are available as options to select when filtering by dataset_id, but others are not. The IAM settings I am familiar with are at the project level, so there must be a dataset-specific setting that determines whether a dataset appears in the filter list, or not. Anyone aware of what that setting might be?

I'm talking about the dropdown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM8dP.png)